# Replacing NumPy array entries with their frequencies / values from dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

Problem: From two input arrays, I want to output an array with the frequency of True values (from input_2) corresponding to each value of input_1.

```
import numpy as np   # import everything from numpy
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
input_1 = np.array([3,6,6,3,6,4])
input_2 = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, True])
```

For this example output that I want is:

```
output_1 = np.array([0,2,2,0,2,1])
```

My current approach involves editing input_1, so only the values corresponding to True remain:

```
locs=np.where(input_2==True,input_1,0)
```

Then counting the frequency of each answer, creating a dictionary and replacing the appropriate keys of input_1 to values (the True frequencies).

```
loc_freq = itemfreq(locs)
dic = {}
for key,val in loc_freq:
    dic[key]=val
print dic
for k, v in dic.iteritems():
    input_1[input_1==k]=v
```

which outputs [3,2,2,3,2,1].

The problem here is twofold: 
1) this still does not do anything with the keys that are not in the dictionary (and should therefore be changed to 0). For example, how can I get the 3s transformed into 0s?
2) This seems very inelegant / ineffective. Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.bincount` is what you are looking for.

```
output_1 = np.bincount(input_1[input_2])[input_1]
```

Answer (score 3):

@memecs solution is correct, +1. However it will be very slow and take a lot of memory if the values in `input_1` are really large, i.e. they are not indices of an array, but say they are seconds or some other integer data that can take very large values.

In that case, you have that `np.bincount(input_1[input_2]).size` is equal to the largest integer in `input_1` with a `True` value in `input_2`.

It is much faster to use [`unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). We use the first to extract the indices of the unique elements of `input_1`, and then use `bincount` to count how often these indices appear in that same array, and weigh them `1` or `0` based on the value of the array `input_2` (`True` or `False`):

```
# extract unique elements and the indices to reconstruct the array
unq, idx = np.unique(input_1, return_inverse=True)
# calculate the weighted frequencies of these indices
freqs_idx = np.bincount(idx, weights=input_2)
# reconstruct the array of frequencies of the elements
frequencies = freqs_idx[idx]
print(frequencies)
```

This solution is really fast and has the minimum memory impact. Credit goes to @Jaime, see his comment below. Below I report my original answer, using `unique` in a different manner.

OTHER POSSIBILITY

It may be faster to go for another solution, using `unique`:

```
import numpy as np
input_1 = np.array([3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 4])
input_2 = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, True])

non_zero_hits, counts = np.unique(input_1[input_2], return_counts=True)
all_hits, idx = np.unique(input_1, return_inverse=True)
frequencies = np.zeros_like(all_hits)

#2nd step, with broadcasting
idx_non_zero_hits_in_all_hits = np.where(non_zero_hits[:, np.newaxis] - all_hits == 0)[1]
frequencies[idx_non_zero_hits_in_all_hits] = counts
print(frequencies[idx])
```

This has the drawback that it will require a lot of memory if the number of unique elements in `input_1` with a `True` value in `input_2` are many, because of the 2D array created and passed to `where`. To reduce the memory footprint, you could use a for loop instead for the 2nd step of the algorithm:

```
#2nd step, but with a for loop.
for j, val in enumerate(non_zero_hits):
    index = np.where(val == all_hits)[0]
    frequencies[index] = counts[j]
print(frequencies[idx])
```

This second solution has a very small memory footprint, but requires a `for` loop. It depends on your typical data input size and values which solution will be best.

Comment: Good point! Memory footprint might be huge. Relabeling the data before using np.bincount s.t. min=0 max < len(input_1) might also be an option. (see skimage.segmentation.relabel_sequential(..))

Comment: Your concerns are very valid, but the proper thing to do is not to build a 2D array, but to use `np.bincount`'s `weights` parameter: `unq, idx = np.unique(array_1, return_inverse=True); freqs = np.bincount(idx, weights=array2)[idx]` will give you a fast, compact and memory efficient implementation.

Comment: @Jaime, I was actually convinced there had to be a better way to do this, and expected you to post a better answer :-) Please post it if you have the time, or will post a community answer later myself

Comment: Feel free to make my comment yours and add it to your answer as you see fit: it's just a variation of the same theme.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted bincount solution is quite elegant, but the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package provides more general solutions to problems of this kind:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = npi.as_index(input_1)
unique_labels, true_count_per_label = npi.group_by(idx).sum(input_2)
print(true_count_per_label[idx.inverse])
```